# Characterization of triangle incenter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\mathbf{x}_3$ be the position vectors for the vertices of a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Let  $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfy $$
\frac{\mathbf{x}_2-\mathbf{x}_1}{\text{area}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2)}+ \frac{\mathbf{x}_3-\mathbf{x}_2}{\text{area}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}_2,\mathbf{x}_3)}+ \frac{\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_3}{\text{area}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}_3,\mathbf{x}_1)}=\mathbf{0}.
$$
I have noticed that in few special  cases, that the orthogonal projection of $\mathbf{x}$ onto the triangle gives the triangle’s incenter.

Is this just a coincidence? I have tried working in trilinear coordinates but didn't make much (i.e. any!) progress.